# ionic - content of page only visible after clicking menu toggle

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I am following a tutorial that displays products of a WooCommerce store. In general I am using the ionic sidebar template.

Problem: The content of my HomePage is not visible. Only after I click the menu toggle button, the content becomes visible instantly. It seems to be a caching/loading problem.

home.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
<ion-grid>

  <ion-row  *ngFor="let product of products">
    <ion-card>
      <ion-card-header>
        Name: {{product.name}}
      </ion-card-header>

      <ion-card-content>
        <img [src]="product.images[0].src">
      </ion-card-content>

    </ion-card>
  </ion-row>

</ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import * as WC from 'woocommerce-api';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

WooCommerce: any;
products: any;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

    this.WooCommerce = WC({

        url: "http://localhost:8888/wordpress/",
        consumerKey: 'ck_.....',
        consumerSecret: 'cs_....',
        wpAPI: true,
        version: 'wc/v1'
    });

    this.WooCommerce.getAsync("products").then((data) =>{

        console.log(JSON.parse(data.body));

        this.products = JSON.parse(data.body);
        console.log(typeof this.products);
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });


}

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's because something very interesting and powerful called Zones. If the concept is new for you, please refer to [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/22/understanding-zones.html) and [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html) for a great explanation.

As you can read there,

> Application state change is caused by three things:
>
> 1) Events - User events like click, change, input, submit, …
>
> 2) XMLHttpRequests - E.g. when fetching data from a remote service
>   Timers -
>
> 3) setTimeout(),setInterval(), because JavaScript
>
> … it turns out that these are the only cases when Angular is actually
>   interested in updating the view.

So I think you'd need to let Angular know when your async operation has ended by using `ngZone`:

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class HomePage {

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private ngZone: NgZone) {

    this.WooCommerce = WC({

        url: "http://localhost:8888/wordpress/",
        consumerKey: 'ck_.....',
        consumerSecret: 'cs_....',
        wpAPI: true,
        version: 'wc/v1'
    });

    this.WooCommerce.getAsync("products").then((data) =>{

        console.log(JSON.parse(data.body));

        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          // Update the products inside the zone so angular is
          // aware of it, and knows that the view should be updated
          this.products = JSON.parse(data.body); 
        });

        console.log(typeof this.products);
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });


}
```